# Apply class to nth element from parameter

Tags: php

i have a function like:

```
draw_process( $active_element ) {

    $step1 = $active_element == 1 ? 'active' : '';
    $step2 = $active_element == 2 ? 'active' : '';
    $step3 = $active_element == 3 ? 'active' : '';

    return '<div class="process">
                <div class="' . $step1 . '">Lorem Ipsum</div>
                <div class="' . $step2 . '">Lorem Ipsum</div>
                <div class="' . $step3 . '">Lorem Ipsum</div>
           </div>';
}
```

Is there an easier way to apply the proper class ('active') to the nth element that was passed into the function?

Comment: Have you considered a `for` loop?

Answer (score 1):

Use a loop.

```
$result = '<div class="process">';
for ($i = 1; $i <= 3; $i++) {
    $class = $i == $active_element ? 'active' : '';
    $result .= "<div class='$class'>Lorum ipsum</div>";
}
$result .= '</div>';
return $result;
```

Comment: Good idea, i was into that first, but forgot about it because, sometimes there is more or less than 3 elements in my process bar

Comment: Replace the hard-coded 3 with however you figure out how many items to put there.

Comment: I assume in the real code there's also dynamic text, not `Lorum ipsum` in every item. If they're in an array, use `foreach ($items as $i => $text)`